# fpdf display image from database invalid image data

Tags: php, fpdf

I am able store and fetch blob image from the database. After researching here about this kind of stuff, by using [MemImage](http://www.fpdf.org/~~V/en/script/script45.php) class on fpdf to be able to display blob images from database, my problem is that it still displays an error "FPDF error: Invalid image data". I can assure you that proper classes are extended. How to resolve this issue? Please help me.

**Fetched data from database:**

```
string '‰PNG


���
IHDR���������óÿa���gAMA��¯È7Šé���tEXtSoftware�Adobe ImageReadyqÉe<��ŸIDAT8Ë¥“ëKSaÇý;vÎvl dD!‚„P{$;š
Å¼,KÓÝ½Ò6cØL‹2r^ÆH)-³ÔjsNmêÔæÖ”2qÙQBÌ½éBµat±oçìÅL#zàÏçó{®q�âþ'ø‰r§ê³=)LÆãýaéˆ8,u%2Rg¢>Ý¾W´« Ï›JË<É!G†›Aú–»¢é\lF‰ë$½THÒCÑ;
ØªtæxRäêœÎÕ~Ø^^ƒi®2®ïXíCãLØø‘dŸÞ&Èñ¤3ÝIëÌM¬   ”¡Â_ÍÌèØ”³©ö…ýõ=\œª€ØB®‹¯“Â˜@æN2¨Æ²¢•9˜UÞSPLB1U�õT!Ükƒ0x•p°’Üž#H¸Bb‚Œ1Ól†5Ø„
_1”Oä,˜å$O>Æß¸ÀµPd
mÏa›kD|=ÉÄGí  Vn£6 Ö[Ä®d�‹æ¡š(ÄØÚPþ±ùmÏ.Á0QŒ¾`'Fb#&Ü§6ú—»aô«Pë×âÓ×Qèý—·1Ø2[µ+z÷iô; ¨ù]ÐC17æ›Ð¾pºI9Ì¾jD¾}ŽÂ›?7ayzeÎ,hXAK í^3¨*bk©·ù@ì+wQ=!‡Ú}uÓåXz·€¶Ù”‡Âq:gì¯º‘n=ª’Ø:Äd+_¸½³Gƒ‡ÌTŽæA;œÕJÎÆ£¥.‡Š!PóÖ)5!Üö›H:¾ˆ˜Üep°’Ö€úÑ"œ–£•Ý‚…õÎ"ðKy¦w|Ê{Hš2!i‡í~3z_XÑ;o…ÅkBZK*
^ˆRô®Ÿ‰:OŠ(¡§jF å…*^˜­È°ÑS¥„è¯¿ñ_ógÐ¬åyºÔc����IEND®B`‚' (length=781)
```

**Code:**

```
if ($result = $image_obj->getImageFromDatabase()) {
        $pdf->MemImage($result, 50, 30);
}
```

Error:

```
FPDF error: Invalid image data
```

Comment: You need to use require('mem_image.php'); and then call PDF_MemImage() as per example in http://www.fpdf.org/~~V/en/script/script45.php

Comment: @VikasUmrao hello thanks for answering! Yes sir I already added. The required classes are extended/required. What would be the possible error for this? Is the fetched data from the database wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try this:
 $pdf->MemImage(base64_decode($result), 50, 30);